# Do I need to protect data structures on iPhone from callbacks and timers?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Do I need mutexes to protect my data structures across UI related callbacks and timer events?

Comment: What type of operation are you doing that you are concerned about? This may help, perhaps, but, what resources are you sharing that may be a concern?  If it is just datastructures, why would you have concurrent reads and writes? http://stalintechnologies.blogspot.com/2008/09/theory-on-rmutex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's accessing your data structures from cocoa touch?  If you set data for a view, it's retained there and it's own copy is used.  You really only have to worry about your own code.

Comment: Well I have some data structures that are used to fuel the UITableView.  And the underlying contents can be updated by a timer callback which gets its data from a web server.  I am worried about a user touching a cell when the contents can get updated.  In any event this is a concern because my application is crashing with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<XXXController 0x5c160f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key scrollView.

Comment: Timers are not executed on a separate thread. They are added to the application's run loop and executed on the main thread. Your crash is most likely caused by a separate issue (the one it's telling you about, most probably).

Comment: @DeShawnT - If that's your error, this question most likely addresses what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481409/app-crashes-when-tab-bar-item-is-selected

Answer (score 2):

All UI-related callbacks are on the main thread. Threads generated by UIKit and other iOS frameworks are generally hidden from the caller. As long as you don't generate threads of your own, you will seldom need to worry about this kind of locking when developing for iOS.